# My tray icon looks bad during Remote Desktop Connection (Windows XP)

Tags: winapi, icons, remote-desktop, system-tray

I'm writing a Windows app that has a tray icon (displayed next to the system clock). The icon itself looks nice if I run it on Windows XP in a normal (console) session, but when I connect to the same Windows XP machine using Remote Desktop Connection the tray icon looks bad—with jagged edges on the side. Note that the rest of the tray icons look fine, it's just mine that looks crappy. So what is the secret here?

Comment: Post a screenshot of the problem please.

Comment: To close voters: how is this OT?  This appears to be an icon resource/color-depth question related to his app.

Comment: RDP defaults to a video setting with 256 colors to limit the amount of data that needs to be sent to get bitmaps across the wire.  This will make your icon look blobby if it contains many colors, the kind that anti-aliased edges generate.  In the RDP startup dialog, select Options, Display tab, set the Colors combo to "Highest Quality".  That's for Win7, forgot what it might look like in XP.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why this question generated such a negative reaction? I fixed the issue by including a 256-color icon along with the one with alpha-channel/anti-aliasing.

Comment: @Hans Passant in Windows XP the colors drop to 16-bit depth, but when connecting to Windows 7 it remained on a 32-bit depth level for me. (I didn't try it with Vista though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue in the past. You have to load icon with `LoadImage` function (not with `LoadIcon`).

Comment: Thanks for actually giving a constructive response. It did help. As I said above, I also made my own version of the icon in 256-color space. Evidently the icon mapper that loads them doesn't do a very good job dealing with anti-aliasing in icons when converting to lower color palletes.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots would be helpful, but I'm guessing it's to do with the colour depth that you're using in the two sessions. If the quality in one is higher than in the other, the icon may render differently.

You can change the colour depth in the display tab of the Remote Desktop Connection settings.

Comment: Well, it would be nice if I could change something in my application to make those jagged edges go away. Do I need to make a special icon for that?

Comment: @ahmd0 Yes you probably do. As I said though, it's difficult to tell without a screenshot.